# Error: [Reanimated] `valueUnpacker` is not a worklet, js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native and this error isn't giving me much to go off of. I was wondering how to solve this. There seem to be a lot of unawnsered similar questions on here so I was wondering if this is new or a common issue.

```
Error: [Reanimated] `valueUnpacker` is not a worklet, js engine: hermes
```

I can't really provide enough of a code sample but I just started a feature with react-native-draggable-flatlist when I got this error.

---- UPDATE -----
I dove into what worklets were and started to learn about the React Natvie Reanimate library where I found that I needed to include the following in my babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function (api) {
    api.cache(true)
    return {
        presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
        plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
    }
}
```

This led me to a new error where I got:

```
Error: [Reanimated] Mismatch between JavaScript part and native part of Reanimated (3.5.1 vs 3.3.0).
See `https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/guides/troubleshooting#mismatch-between-javascript-part-and-native-part-of-reanimated` for more details., js engine: hermes
```

I followed the steps provided and tehre was only one implementation of the package:

```
└─┬ react-native-draggable-flatlist@4.0.1
  └── react-native-reanimated@3.5.1
```

Then I set the override in package.json but I am still getting the same issue with the mixmatch. I even started expo with the -c flag to reset the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found this solution following this:

Solution: Check if you have rebuilt your app after upgrading react-native-reanimated. If you use Expo Go, you must use the exact version which is bundled into Expo SDK.

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/reanimated/

If you followed me then remove the override before starting this process or you will have some issues.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to add the following to package.json: yarn add react-native-reanimated and 
yarn add  react-native-gesture-handler.

Then do the following steps

1-import "react-native-gesture-handler"; 
to App.tsx
2- npx expo start -c

if you are using CLI run the following commands
npx react-native start --reset-cache

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Check if react-native-reanimated version is the exact version bundled into the Expo SDK of your project.

I simply upgraded Expo SDK 48 to 49  using the command:: expo upgrade 49

or

install the exact version of react-native-reanimated compatible with your Expo SDK version

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your babel.config.js should look like this

```js
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        ... // don't add it here :)
    ],
    plugins: [
        ...
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from',
        'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    ],
};
```

add the plugins like above.
Make sure to pod install if your developing for ios with

```
cd ios && pod install && cd ..
```

restart your app with

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Answer (score -1):

Unlike what we used to do in V1 of renimated, your need to DONT use `import 'react-native-reanimated'`; in yout index and App files.
I am resuming that you followed the installation guide constructions, I mean you did add plugins to your babel.config.js.